# Import Tensorflow packages failed

Tags: tensorflow, installation

I'm trying to run the below code in a jupyter notebook and I get the following errors. I checked I have the latest version of tensorflow and all its packages with pip list and they seem to be there. I also enabled jupyter extensions.

Not sure what causes this and any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

```
import tensorflow_model_analysis as tfma
import tensorflow_data_validation as tfdv
from tensorflow_model_analysis.addons.fairness.post_export_metrics import fairness_indicators
from tensorflow_model_analysis.addons.fairness.view import widget_view
from fairness_indicators.examples import util

from witwidget.notebook.visualization import WitConfigBuilder
from witwidget.notebook.visualization import WitWidget


ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bmecu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3325, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-34-51bae98adf5f>", line 11, in <module>
    import tensorflow_model_analysis as tfma
  File "C:\Users\bmecu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_model_analysis\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow_model_analysis.api import tfma_unit as test
  File "C:\Users\bmecu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_model_analysis\api\tfma_unit.py", line 68, in <module>
    from tensorflow_model_analysis import types
  File "C:\Users\bmecu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_model_analysis\types.py", line 31, in <module>
    TensorType = Union[tf.Tensor, tf.SparseTensor]
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Tensor'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bmecu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2039, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'AttributeError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bmecu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\bmecu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\bmecu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\bmecu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\bmecu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bmecu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1101, in get_records
    return _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
  File "C:\Users\bmecu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 319, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bmecu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 353, in _fixed_getinnerframes
    records = fix_frame_records_filenames(inspect.getinnerframes(etb, context))
  File "C:\Users\bmecu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 1502, in getinnerframes
    frameinfo = (tb.tb_frame,) + getframeinfo(tb, context)
  File "C:\Users\bmecu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 1460, in getframeinfo
    filename = getsourcefile(frame) or getfile(frame)
  File "C:\Users\bmecu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 696, in getsourcefile
    if getattr(getmodule(object, filename), '__loader__', None) is not None:
  File "C:\Users\bmecu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 733, in getmodule
    if ismodule(module) and hasattr(module, '__file__'):
  File "C:\Users\bmecu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\bmecu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Users\bmecu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\bmecu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . _api.v2 import audio
  File "C:\Users\bmecu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\_api\v2\audio\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops.gen_audio_ops import decode_wav
  File "C:\Users\bmecu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_audio_ops.py", line 9, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\bmecu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\bmecu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Users\bmecu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\bmecu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\bmecu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bmecu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3325, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-34-51bae98adf5f>", line 11, in <module>
    import tensorflow_model_analysis as tfma
  File "C:\Users\bmecu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_model_analysis\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow_model_analysis.api import tfma_unit as test
  File "C:\Users\bmecu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_model_analysis\api\tfma_unit.py", line 68, in <module>
    from tensorflow_model_analysis import types
  File "C:\Users\bmecu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_model_analysis\types.py", line 31, in <module>
    TensorType = Union[tf.Tensor, tf.SparseTensor]
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Tensor'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bmecu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2039, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'AttributeError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bmecu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\bmecu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\bmecu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\bmecu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\bmecu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Answer (score 0):

try installing the compatible cuda and cudnn for the TensorFlow that you have installed.
check this link: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows

Comment: This was published as an answer, but does not attempt to answer the question. Possibly it should be a comment, otherwise please edit your answer and add an explanation that may be useful.